# Control lamp from FreeBSD

Tags: hardware, freebsd, usb

I have a webcam connected to a FreeBSD server that I want to collect and email an image on a schedule via a cron job. The room it is in may not always be lit. I am hoping to find some solution where a light can illuminate the subject just at the time of the photo. As a first stab, I bought a cheap USB lamp from Amazon and then tried using `usbconfig` to power off its port, but alas, this had no effect on the lamp. (Also, the port seemed to disappear permanently and could no longer be addressed by `usbconfig` -- probably something I just don't understand about the process.)

This server is running FreeBSD 12.1. Does anyone know of a reliable and affordable way to do what I need?

Comment: How often are you taking a photo? A lower tech approach... Have you considered just having a power timer plugged into the wall socket?

Comment: Scheduled for a specific time weekly currently.